# Laravel MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel and I was trying to learn from a youtube tutorial when i faced this problem. I have a signup form and on submit I am posting the form data and trying to save it in my user table but thats when i have recieved this exception MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:.I would appreciate any help to solve this error. below is my code

My controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function postSignUp(Request $request)
    {
       $email=$request['email']; 
       $first_name=$request['first_name'];
       $password= bcrypt($request['password']);

       $user =new User();
       $user->email=$email;
       $user->first_name=$first_name;
       $user->password=$password;

       $user->save();
       return redirect()->back();

    }
    public function postSignIn(Request $request)
    {

    }
}
```

my Router

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::post('/signup', [
    'uses'=>'UserController@postSignUp',
    'as'=>'signup'
]);
```

MY form

```
    <form action="{{route('signup')}}" meathod="post">
         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
         </div>  
         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
         </div>  
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
             <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="passwprd">
         </div>  
         <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign up</button>

         </div>
       <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your open `<form>` tag.

```
meathod="post"
```

should be

```
method="post"
```

You have a typo, so the form is posting as a `GET` instead of the intended `POST`.

---

Unrelated, I suggest using the simpler form of the CSRF input

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

instead of

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
```

Comment: thank you @deefour i spent so much time on checking all other things that I didn't pay attention on typo. but it is working now. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
     <form action="{{route('signup')}}" method="post">
{{ csrf_field() }}
             <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
             </div>  
             <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
             </div>  
             <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                 <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="passwprd">
             </div>  
             <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign up</button>

             </div>
           <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
    </form>
```